# Reading File from Uri gives java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT

Tags: android, image, uri, filenotfoundexception

When picking an image using an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent, I get a URI that I can't open the file from. If I try to open the file, like this:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(uri.getPath()));
```

It gives the following exception:

```
03-11 15:14:36.132  20557-20557/my.package W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:9537: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-11 15:14:36.138  20557-20557/my.package W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
03-11 15:14:36.138  20557-20557/my.package W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
```

`/document/image:9537` seems to indeed be an incorrect path, but how do I get the correct path?

I use this logic to open the image picker:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

And retrieve the Uri in the onActivityResult like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    ....
    Uri uri = data.getData();
```

I need to get the file to do decoding to make it smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I try to open the file, like this:

That will not work for most modern Android devices. Most likely, you received a `content:` `Uri`. This is fairly normal on newer versions of Android. Future versions of Android might block `file:` `Uri` values.

> I need to get the file to do decoding to make it smaller.

There does not have to be a file associated with a given `Uri`. That `Uri` might point to:

- A local file on external storage
- A local file on internal storage for the other app
- A local file on removable storage
- A local file that is encrypted and needs to be decrypted on the fly
- A stream of bytes held in a `BLOB` column in a database
- A piece of content that needs to be downloaded by the other app first
- ...and so on

Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content pointed to by the `Uri`. Then, pass that to your decoding logic, such as `BitmapFactory` and its `decodeStream()` method.

Comment: That is awesome. I just had a misconception of how these uri's work.

Comment: @wvdz: Yeah, it's best to treat them as opaque handles, akin to a URL to a Web site.