# Is it possible to get File Path from FileProvider generated URI?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-fileprovider

Given that at some point I have a URI given to me by some external library, and all FileProvider setup is done correctly (and the URI has been granted read/write permissions), how could I get the path to image on disk that the URI is pointing to?

Let's suppose that the image file is stored at `/sdcard/XYZAppFolder/file.jpg`.

While in debug I can see the string of the URI:

```
content://<applicationID>.provider/<virtualfolder>/file.jpg
```

But when trying to perform a query via ContentResolver, I get index -1:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null, 
cursor.moveToFirst();
int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Images.ImageColumns.DATA);


<paths>
<external-path
        name="virtualfolder"
        path="VISUAPP" />
</paths>
```

Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Any other way to get the absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how could I get the path to image on disk that the URI is pointing to?

You can't, if by "external library" you mean "a third-party app". Also, it is unlikely that you will have access to the file on the filesystem, anyway:

- It may be in internal storage
- It may be in the other app's app-specific location on removable storage
- It may be in locations on external storage which your app cannot access on Android Q (by default with a `targetSdkVersion` of 29 or higher) or Android R (for all apps, apparently)

If by "external library" you mean a library in your own app, you could try reading in the `FileProvider` metadata XML resource and use that to figure out what root and path match the `<virtualfolder>` path segment. From there, you could generate a `File` that points to the location from that root, the metadata path, and the rest of the `Uri` path.

> But when trying to perform a query via ContentResolver, I get index -1:

`FileProvider` does not support a `DATA` column. Android Q and higher also block the `DATA` column from similar sorts of queries (e.g., on `MediaStore`), so any code that you have that relies on it is likely to have problems starting very soon.

Use `ContentResolver` (e.g., `openInputStream()`) to work with the `Uri`.

Comment: is Android R available anywhere ?

Comment: @VivekMishra: That is the 2020 major release. BTW, I may have misinterpreted "external library" -- see the updated answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare then how do i sent the image to server? I need the image path and without getting imagepath i can't create multipart request to server to upload the image.

Comment: @sak: Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56308643/115145): "[This blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html) demonstrates how to use `InputStreamRequestBody` (specifically a Kotlin port of the original) to upload content in this fashion. [This blog post](https://cketti.de/2020/05/23/content-uris-and-okhttp/) provides another look at the same problem and a similar solution."