# Record video from camera and upload on server android

Tags: java, android, http

I am developing an `android` app and recording a video and uploading it on server is one feature of it. I have been researching alot how to upload the recorded video on server but all the answers on SO and all the articles that I have read are using `MultipartEntity`. Now, what I have been wondering is that MultipartEntity is deprecated quite a while ago and I couldn't find any other way to upload a video on server so is there any `library` or something that android has introduced for uploading the video on server after deprecating MultipartEntity? If yes, please send me a link. Secondly, if I still use MultipartEntity in my android app, will it cause any problems/bugs in the future?

Comment: "MultipartEntity is deprecated quite a while ago" -- there is no `MultipartEntity` in the Android SDK. This might be from Apache HttpClient, which was removed from the Android SDK a few years ago. OkHttp is a popular alternative: https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-a-multipart-request-kt-java

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using Intent to launch the camera and then in my onActivityResult() method, the intent returns me uri of the video file so can we use OkHttp to send this video file to server?

Comment: There are a few implementations of `InputStreamRequestBody` that you can use for this -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308559/create-a-file-from-a-photo-uri-on-android

Answer (score 0):

recorded video is also a file, sou you can use for example retrofit 2 to upload a file to server