# how to copy file and get Uri (with read permisssion) using android ResultLauncher in android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, android-external-storage, activity-result-api

trying to get file(PDF) form internal storage to upload on server with the help of Android `ResultLauncher` API, getting Uri in result but I am unable to read that Uri.
When trying to copy that file to my app's scope directory with the help of result Uri,
getting permission error on `contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)`. this is the error:

```
Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri <my file uri>  requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

How can I copy file in app's scope directory?
This is my ResultLauncher:

```
singleTypeResultLauncher =
            fragment.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()){
                    result ->
                result?.let{
                    val tempUri = Uri.parse(it.toString().replace("%3A", ":"))

                    val path = createCopyAndReturnRealPath(fragment.requireContext(), tempUri)
                }
            }
```

this is how I am launching:

```
singleTypeResultLauncher.launch("application/pdf")
```

this is method in with app is crashing:

```
crashing on val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)

fun createCopyAndReturnRealPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver ?: return null
        val mimeType = getMimeType(context, uri).getSafe()
        val fileExt = "." + mimeType.substring(mimeType.indexOf('/') + 1)
        val filePath: String = (context.dataDir.absolutePath + File.separator
                + System.currentTimeMillis())
        val file = File(filePath)
        try {
            file.parentFile.mkdirs()
            file.createNewFile()
            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) ?: return null //crashing here
            val outputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            val buf = ByteArray(1024)
            var len: Int
            while (inputStream.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) outputStream.write(buf, 0, len)
            outputStream.close()
            inputStream.close()
        } catch (ignore: IOException) {
            return null
        }
        return file.absolutePath
    }
```

using provider paths:

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to read that Uri

You are not trying to read that `Uri`. You are trying to read a different `Uri`:

```kotlin
val tempUri = Uri.parse(it.toString().replace("%3A", ":"))
```

Replace that with:

```kotlin
val tempUri = it
```

...or, just remove `tempUri` entirely and use `it` directly.

> trying to get file(PDF) form internal storage to upload on server

Note that [you do not necessarily need to copy the content to upload it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56308643/115145).