# FileNotFound, open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) on Android 12 Scoped Storage

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file, android-storage, scoped-storage

When I tried to convert the file selected by the user to request body, I got the error FileNotFound, open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) on Android 12. I was trying to upload a user-selected pdf using Retrofit Multipart Upload.

For calling intent I have used `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`

```
file.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull()
```

Do I need to use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` gives you a `Uri`. It may or may not represent a file on the filesystem, let alone one that you can access. Use the `Uri` itself, with an `InputStreamRequestBody`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308559/create-a-file-from-a-photo-uri-on-android

Comment: your problem solved?