# Why i cant Fetch the Gallery From my Desktop

Tags: android, android-intent, file-upload, deprecated, startactivityforresult

[Its showing device folder when i am trying to upload an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6ssB.png)

i tried to upload the image but its not working
[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KWWN.png)

```
//is there any Error in this code?

private void openGallery() {
    Intent pickImage= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickImage,REQ);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQ && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri uri=data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        noticeImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try setting the type of file you want like this: `pickImage.setType("image/*");`

Comment: Also, look here for discussions about this problem and possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308559/create-a-file-from-a-photo-uri-on-android