# I can't retrieve the real path for file uploads on Android version 13 phones

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload, android-file, android-version

I used this object to get the real path of a selected file from its URI:

```
object RealPathUtil {
fun getRealPath(context: Context, fileUri: Uri): String? {
    val realPath: String?
    // SDK < API11
    realPath = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(context, fileUri)
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(context, fileUri)
    } else {
        getRealPathFromURI_API19(context, fileUri)
    }
    return realPath
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
fun getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(context: Context?, contentUri: Uri?): String? {
    val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
    var result: String? = null
    val cursorLoader = CursorLoader(
        context!!, contentUri!!, proj, null, null, null
    )
    val cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground()
    if (cursor != null) {
        val column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        result = cursor.getString(column_index)
        cursor.close()
    }
    return result
}

fun getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(context: Context, contentUri: Uri?): String {
    val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(contentUri!!, proj, null, null, null)
    var column_index = 0
    var result = ""
    if (cursor != null) {
        column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        result = cursor.getString(column_index)
        cursor.close()
        return result
    }
    return result
}

/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri     The Uri to query.
 * @author paulburke
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
fun getRealPathFromURI_API19(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    val isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
            val type = split[0]
            if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
            }
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id)
            )
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
            val type = split[0]
            var contentUri: Uri? = null
            if ("image" == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            } else if ("video" == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            } else if ("audio" == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }
            val selection = "_id=?"
            val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
                split[1]
            )
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
        }
    } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {

        // Return the remote address
        return if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) uri.lastPathSegment else getDataColumn(
            context,
            uri,
            null,
            null
        )
    } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
        return uri.path
    }
    return null
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context       The context.
 * @param uri           The Uri to query.
 * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
fun getDataColumn(
    context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?,
    selectionArgs: Array<String>?
): String? {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    val column = "_data"
    val projection = arrayOf(
        column
    )
    try {
        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            uri!!, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
            null
        )
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
            return cursor.getString(index)
        }
    } finally {
        cursor?.close()
    }
    return null
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content" == uri.authority
}}
```

In this method, Android version 13 devices return a null value. On the other hand, in devices with different Android versions, I can successfully retrieve the real path from the URI.
[image: Passing uri for getting real path]

you can see im getting null value after passing the uri im getting from file selection:
[image: getting null value]

Can anyone suggest how I can address file uploading issues on Android version 13 phones?

Comment: "I used this object to get the real path of a selected file from its URI" -- that has never worked reliably. A `Uri` does not have to point to anything that you can access on the filesystem. "how I can address file uploading issues" -- use the `Uri` itself. For example, if you are using OkHttp/Retrofit and `RequestBody`, you can create an `InputStreamRequestBody`, as is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56308643/115145) and [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html) and [here](https://cketti.de/2020/05/23/content-uris-and-okhttp/).

Comment: Even if you would manage to get 'a real path' then that would not help you as you would not have a READ permission for it. You only got a READ permission using the uri.

Comment: You should have posted the obtained uri as text. Not in an image.

Comment: Further you should have tolld us where a null was returned. What was it that you did not cover?